# Canvas custom shape fill issue

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I need to create custom shape in Canvas for showing the graph in a human shape.
I have created the shape, but when I try to fill it, it is not getting properly filled. i.e some part is missing and some is overflowing.

This is the link to my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vqbjqndm/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();

  context.arc(65,60 ,35,0,Math.PI*2,true);

  context.moveTo(5,100);
  context.lineTo(5, 300);
  context.moveTo(35,300); 
  context.arc(20, 300, 15, 0, Math.PI);

  context.moveTo(35,300);
  context.lineTo(35, 250);
  context.lineTo(95, 250);
  context.lineTo(95, 300);

  context.moveTo(125,300);
  context.arc(110, 300, 15, 0, Math.PI);
  context.moveTo(125,300);
  context.lineTo(125,100);
  context.lineTo(5, 100);

  context.fill();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting in trouble when you're drawing the cirles.

You're at (5, 300), then you move to (35,300) and now you draw your circle back to (5, 100), then move back to (35, 300). That's gonna mess your mask up.

Instead, you can draw the circle counter-clockwise by adding the parameter `true` at the end of the acr()-function:

Before: `context.arc(110, 300, 15, 0, Math.PI);`

After: `context.arc(110, 300, 15, Math.PI, 0, true);`

As you can see I also reversed radian-values

http://jsfiddle.net/Niddro/vqbjqndm/4/